# In CommandButton immediate="true" but validation not skipped?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have added `immediate="true"` in button

```
 <h:commandButton id="browse" action="#{creationBean.getATerminationRoot()}" value="Browse" immediate="true">
    <rich:componentControl  event="click" target="aTermPanel" operation="show" /></h:commandButton>
```

Now in same page i have included another page like below

```
<ui:insert name="name">                 
<ui:include src="../pages/abc.xhtml" />                 
</ui:insert>
```

This page have some validation in `inputtextbox`

```
<h:inputText id="ammOnDemandId" required="true"
value="#{var.amount}"
requiredMessage="Msg1"
validatorMessage="msg2">
<f:validateRequired />
<f:validateLongRange minimum="0" maximum="9999999">
</f:validateLongRange>
<rich:validator event="blur" />
</h:inputText>
```

Note:- This included page have another `<h:form>`

If i am removing these validation everything working fine in parent page and clicking on button data is loaded but when i am adding validation in this included page textbox button not working due to validation fail.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your h:commandButton trigger two things :

-> an http request which expecting a refresh or redirect of the page
-> an non-http action which shows up a new panel in the current page

Maybe jsf don't know how to deal with this contradiction.